# Microphone not working at all on a Toshiba sattelite p505 s8980

Tags: 11.10, microphone, toshiba-satellite

- My built-in microphone doesn't work in "record audio" program and in
  Skype.
- I'm using ubuntu 11.10 in Toshiba sattelite p505 s8980.
- No mute button checked I have PulseAudio Volume Control installed 
  currently when aim trying to use  record audio program and hear what 
  I record it plays  noisy sound not my voice
- I changed my computer from 'Analog Stereo Output' to 'Analog
  Stereo Duplex', in both sound setting ( ubuntu ) and in 
  PulseAudio Volume Control
- no problem in    bios  and in my windows seven sound worked perfectly
  and in ubuntu no    problem in sound at all i can play music and
  movies and even in skype    i can hear the sounf of who is taking to
  me ( it's about the    microphone only "

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem it's been driving me crazy.

Here's what worked for me edit the alsa options

If I run `alsamixer` I don't see any mic channels. (Press F4 for capture)

SCREEN SHOT REMOVED

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add the following line at the end

```
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop
```

Another post said restart alsa with sudo alsa force-reload. This does not work. Restart the laptop completely.

After restarting run `alsamixer`again. This time F4 yields

SCREEN SHOT REMOVED

Notice that Mic B is selected for capture. Change that to Mic F

SCREEN SHOT REMOVED

That's it now the regular sound control should show mic input.

Answer (score 1):

I've opened a terminal and type alsamixer. This will open the alsamixer in the terminal. Hit the 'F4'-key it showed me the 'capture' device settings. Then the 4th item displayed  as Mic, I changed this to 'Internal Mic' (click array down/up key to change).

Once done, I checked in 'system-settings' --> sound --> hardware and I saw the missing lights appearing. Did a test with 'sound record' and this was working.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your audio profile is set to "Analog stereo duplex" in the System settings -> Sound configurations. This solved for me, because it was configured for "analog stereo output" only. You might want to change your audio profile only when you're going to use an HDMI output, for example.